# java.sql.Timestamp ZoneOffset mismatch with java.time

Tags: java, timestamp, java-8, java-time, timestamp-with-timezone

`Instant inst = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);` --> `2015-10-19T00:00:00Z`

`Timestamp.from(inst)` --> `2015-10-19 11:00:00.0`

Why is java.sql.Timestamp adding my local timezone (+11) after conversion?

Comment: I would assume it's about timezones. What's your local offset from UTC?

Comment: If you dump both the `inst` and `Timestamp` millisecond values, there are both the same, `1445212800000`, it's most likely `Timestamp` is presenting the value in the local time zone

Comment: Hi, my local timezone is +11 but I need to know how the right way to get java.sql.Timestamp of LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)

Comment: *"Hi, my local timezone is +11 but I need to know how the right way to get java.sql.Timestamp of LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC) "* - You already have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, if we take your code...

```
Instant inst = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from(inst);

System.out.println(inst);
System.out.println(ts);
```

which prints...

```
2015-10-19T00:00:00Z
2015-10-19 11:00:00.0
```

which admittly is probably unexpected, but if we add...

```
System.out.println(inst.toEpochMilli());
System.out.println(ts.getTime());
```

which outputs

```
1445212800000
1445212800000
```

you can see that both values are actually the same thing, but the `Timestamp` is having the local time zone applied to it when it's been printed

Now, if instead, we do something like...

```
Instant inst = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from(inst);

System.out.println(inst);
System.out.println(ts);
System.out.println(inst.toEpochMilli());
System.out.println(ts.getTime());
```

using the system's time zone, it prints

```
2015-10-18T13:00:00Z
2015-10-19 00:00:00.0
1445173200000
1445173200000
```

So, the question then becomes, which one is more important to you?  Personally, I think what you had was more important

Comment: ok... so it is a matter of string conversion what leads me to the next question... thank you @madprogrammer